# Ways of retrieving photos, notes from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos.app, notes.app

I'm trying to copy photos and notes from my iPhone 6 to my macbook. The phone was synced to my old computer which suffered a hard drive failure, so I'm trying to save whatever I can from my phone before syncing it to the new one. I haven't had any luck with iCloud and would really like to avoid dming every note and photo to myself one by one :/ Any help appreciated.

Comment: What does "haven't had any luck with iCloud" mean, what exactly was the problem you run into? Setting up iCloud sync is most probably the easiest way to solve this, so it might be worth some time to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

For photos, please ask a separate question. As for notes:

1. Airdrop
2. *Collaborate* with the Apple ID in your new Mac
3. Save to files as text if the notes don't have any photos, and import them back to Notes on new Mac
4. Easiest one, set up iCloud notes on the new Mac with the same Apple ID as the iPhone.